# How to append a tbody after removing tbody using jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

```
if ($("#ddlRateCode").next().val() != "MYKL GROSS") {
                                    $("#compRecord tbody").remove();
                                    $("#compRecord tbody").append("<tr class='compensationRecords'>" +
                        "<td class='tdCompRateCode table_td'>" + $("#ddlRateCode").next().val() + "</td>" +
                        "<td class='tdCompRate table_td'>" + $("#txtCompRate").val() + "</td>" +
                        "<td class='tdCompPercent table_td'>" + $("#txtCompPercent").val() + "</td>" +
                        "<input type='hidden' value='" + $("#ddlRateCode").val() + "' class='tdRateCodeId' />" +
                        "<td class='table_td'><button class='edit'>Edit</button>" +
                        "<button class='btnDelete'>Delete</button></td>" +
                        "</tr>");
                                }
```

Comment: I think you have to describe your problem a little more if you want an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#compRecord").append("<tbody><tr>...</tr></tbody>");
```

If that is not what you are looking for, you'll need to describe your problem better. Just the question in the head and some random code without explanation isn't a good question.